# Voiceover on iPhone using Safari skips iFrame content

Tags: html, iframe, mobile-safari, accessibility, voiceover

When a webpage contains an iFrame, voiceover completely skips over the content of the iFrame as though it does not exist. (swiping left/right)

This behaviour is only noticeable on iOS (latest) + safari. Other browsers such as Opera mini, Chrome or Mercury don't experience this problem.

Is there someway to "force" Safari to read the contents of the iFrame.
Note that you can click into the iframe to access its content... but this is not ideal for visually impaired users.

Comment: Can you add some sample code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Add any iframe to a page.
Example:
<iframe id="forecast_embed" type="text/html" frameborder="0" height="245" width="100%" src="http://forecast.io/embed/#lat=42.3583&lon=-71.0603&name=Downtown Boston&color=#00aaff&font=Georgia&units=uk"> </iframe>

Comment: You need to put `https://` before `forecast.io` for the iframe to load. I tried your source code with that change and it worked fine. I'm not sure if that was the exact issue you had though. If not, can you provide a sample URL?

Comment: Hi. Try:
http://ass3.netne.net/
Using iOS and VoiceOver the weather widget is completely skipped (using swipe right/left)

Comment: I get an error 404 on that page.

Comment: Page loading here fine... its one of those free hosting sites.. so might have been down when u tried.